# Checking for Repeated Strings in 2d list

Tags: python

i have a program where i have a list of names and classes. i have the list in alphabetical order. now im trying to check if names repeat, add the classes to one single name.

im trying to write some code like

go through names if name is already in list, add the class to the one name. so an example would be, instead of having

```
['Anita','phys 1443'], ['Anita','IE 3312']
```

i would just have

```
['Anita','PHYS 1443','IE 3312']
```

How would i go about doing this in a logival way, WITHOUT using any sort of built in functions? i tried comparing indices like

```
if list[i][0] == list[i+1][0]
```

append `list[i+1][1]` to an emptylist. while that almost worked, it would screw up at some points along the way. here is my attempt

```
size = len(c)
i = 0
c = [['Anita', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Anita', 'IE 3312'], ['Beihuang', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'MATH 1426'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'IE 3312'], ['Christopher', 'CSE 1310'], ['Dylan', 'CSE 1320'], ['Edmund', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Ian', 'IE 3301'], ['Ian', 'CSE 1320'], ['Ian', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Isis', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Jonathan', 'MATH 2325'], ['Krishna', 'MATH 2325'], ['Michael', 'IE 3301'], ['Nang', 'MATH 2325'], ['Ram', 'CSE 1320'], ['Taesu', 'CSE 1320'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'IE 3312'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'MATH 2325'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'CSE 1310']]
## Check if any names repeat
d.append(c[0][0])
while i < size - 1 :
    if c[i][0] == c[i+1][0] :

        d.append(c[i][1])
        d.append(c[i+1][1])
    else :
        d.append(c[i+1][0])
        d.append(c[i+1][1])
    i = i + 1
print d
```

output was.

```
['Anita', 'PHYS 1443', 'IE 3312', 'Beihuang', 'PHYS 1443', 'Chiao-Lin', 'MATH 1426', 'MATH 1426', 'IE 3312', 'Christopher', 'CSE 1310', 'Dylan', 'CSE 1320', 'Edmund', 'PHYS 1443', 'Ian', 'IE 3301', 'IE 3301', 'CSE 1320', 'CSE 1320', 'PHYS 1443', 'Isis', 'PHYS 1443', 'Jonathan', 'MATH 2325', 'Krishna', 'MATH 2325', 'Michael', 'IE 3301', 'Nang', 'MATH 2325', 'Ram', 'CSE 1320', 'Taesu', 'CSE 1320', "Tre'Shaun", 'IE 3312', 'IE 3312', 'MATH 2325', 'MATH 2325', 'CSE 1310']
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this:

```
d = []
vi = 0
c = [['Anita', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Anita', 'IE 3312'], ['Beihuang', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'MATH 1426'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'IE 3312'], ['Christopher', 'CSE 1310'], ['Dylan', 'CSE 1320'], ['Edmund', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Ian', 'IE 3301'], ['Ian', 'CSE 1320'], ['Ian', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Isis', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Jonathan', 'MATH 2325'], ['Krishna', 'MATH 2325'], ['Michael', 'IE 3301'], ['Nang', 'MATH 2325'], ['Ram', 'CSE 1320'], ['Taesu', 'CSE 1320'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'IE 3312'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'MATH 2325'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'CSE 1310']]
size = len(c)
## Check if any names repeat
while i < size - 1:
    if c[i][0] == c[i+1][0] :
        temp = c[i]
        temp.append(c[i+1][1])
        d.append(temp)
    else :
        d.append(c[i+1])
    i = i + 1
print d
```

**Output**

```
>>> [['Anita', 'PHYS 1443', 'IE 3312'], ['Beihuang', 'PHYS 1443'],...,
    ["Tre'Shaun", 'MATH 2325', 'CSE 1310']]
```

Comment: close but not correct. some names have repeat 3 times so that has to be accounted for as well which is what screws my program

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this using collection's `defaultdict`. You can use `defaultdict` to create a dictionary where every key maps to an empty list by default, and so you can accumulate the values for each person in your list.

```
In [1]: c = [['Anita', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Anita', 'IE 3312'], ['Beihuang', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'MATH 1426'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'IE 3312'], ['Christopher', 'CSE 1310'], ['Dylan', 'CSE 1320'], ['Edmund', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Ian', 'IE 3301'], ['Ian', 'CSE 1320'], ['Ian', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Isis', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Jonathan', 'MATH 2325'], ['Krishna', 'MATH 2325'], ['Michael', 'IE 3301'], ['Nang', 'MATH 2325'], ['Ram', 'CSE 1320'], ['Taesu', 'CSE 1320'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'IE 3312'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'MATH 2325'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'CSE 1310']]
In [2]: from collections import defaultdict
In [3]: result = defaultdict(list)
In [4]: for a in c:
            result[a[0]].append( a[1] )
In [5]: result
Out[1]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Krishna': ['MATH 2325'], 'Dylan': ['CSE 1320'], 'Isis': ['PHYS 1443'], 'Jonathan': ['MATH 2325'], 'Ram': ['CSE 1320'], 'Michael': ['IE 3301'], 'Nang': ['MATH 2325'], 'Ian': ['IE 3301', 'CSE 1320', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Christopher': ['CSE 1310'], 'Edmund': ['PHYS 1443'], "Tre'Shaun": ['IE 3312', 'MATH 2325', 'CSE 1310'], 'Beihuang': ['PHYS 1443'], 'Chiao-Lin': ['MATH 1426', 'IE 3312'], 'Anita': ['PHYS 1443', 'IE 3312'], 'Taesu': ['CSE 1320']})
```

You can then convert this dictionary back to a list:

```
In [6]: list_result = [ [k] + v for k, v in result.items() ]
In [7]: list_result
Out[2]: [['Krishna', 'MATH 2325'],
 ['Dylan', 'CSE 1320'],
 ['Isis', 'PHYS 1443'],
 ['Jonathan', 'MATH 2325'],
 ['Ram', 'CSE 1320'],
 ['Michael', 'IE 3301'],
 ['Nang', 'MATH 2325'],
 ['Ian', 'IE 3301', 'CSE 1320', 'PHYS 1443'],
 ['Christopher', 'CSE 1310'],
 ['Edmund', 'PHYS 1443'],
 ["Tre'Shaun", 'IE 3312', 'MATH 2325', 'CSE 1310'],
 ['Beihuang', 'PHYS 1443'],
 ['Chiao-Lin', 'MATH 1426', 'IE 3312'],
 ['Anita', 'PHYS 1443', 'IE 3312'],
 ['Taesu', 'CSE 1320']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this corrects the logic you are looking for:

```
c = [['Anita', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Anita', 'IE 3312'], ['Anita', 'CS169'], ['Beihuang', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'MATH 1426'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'IE 3312'], ['Christopher', 'CSE 1310'], ['Dylan', 'CSE 1320'], ['Edmund', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Ian', 'IE 3301'], ['Ian', 'CSE 1320'], ['Ian', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Isis', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Jonathan', 'MATH 2325'], ['Krishna', 'MATH 2325'], ['Michael', 'IE 3301'], ['Nang', 'MATH 2325'], ['Ram', 'CSE 1320'], ['Taesu', 'CSE 1320'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'IE 3312'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'MATH 2325'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'CSE 1310']]

i = 0
d = list()
size = len(c)
## Check if any names repeat
while i < (size - 1):
    if(c[i][0] == c[i+1][0]):
        #append the next course in itself. 
        c[i].append(c[i+1][1])
        #remove the next entry, since we have included the course in that author
        c.remove(c[i+1])
        #decrease the size of iteration by 1
        size -= 1
    else:
        #when next entry is not with same name, append it in d
        d.append(c[i])
        #and move on
        i += 1

print(d)
```

Result:

```
[['Anita', 'PHYS 1443', 'IE 3312', 'CS169'], ['Beihuang', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Chiao-Lin', 'MATH 1426', 'IE 3312'], ['Christopher', 'CSE 1310'], ['Dylan', 'CSE 1320'], ['Edmund', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Ian', 'IE 3301', 'CSE 1320'], ['Ian', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Isis', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Jonathan', 'MATH 2325'], ['Krishna', 'MATH 2325'], ['Michael', 'IE 3301'], ['Nang', 'MATH 2325'], ['Ram', 'CSE 1320'], ['Taesu', 'CSE 1320'], ["Tre'Shaun", 'IE 3312', 'MATH 2325']]
```

EDIT: Added to handle the case when more than 2 entries with same author name exists.

Comment: ok ok i see what your doing there. the problem occures when one person has more then 3 classes associated with them. example ian has three classes so he showed up 2 times on your output. and tre shaun only had 2 classes behind his name even though he took 3. im starting to want to change my method because i can never seem to get it right

Comment: Yes, There was some problem with the way you were appending things :)

Comment: @Zach: I have updated the code with some indentation gotchas I earlier had. This should work as expected now

Comment: it did with the exception of tre shaun. im just gonna append the last indexe's and call it a day. been at this for too long haha